# Integration tests for an external web service

Tags: .net, testing, wsdl, integration-testing

I work with external WSDL-based services and have some difficulties in testing app parts that interacts with them.

Now I'm using manual testing but it's really hard to do it because these services have a time dependency factor and work with very verbose objects (they have a very deep nesting). Also one service can dependent on a response gotten from another service.

So I'm looking for best practices how to test these interactions in a more automatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can test these external WSDL's. Here are some of the tools you can use to test these interactions in a more automatic way:

- [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/): Although this is a Java based application, you can use this to simulate interactions with various web services. Its a great tool to help augment any Webservice testing you may have. Any scripts you create then can be added to any CI as part of an automated strategy to validate the services. This tool is good because if you have many different languages implementing your various WSDL's, you can use the same tool to cover all those languages/frameworks. The *learning curve* is very short with [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html), so you can get up-and-running pretty quickly.
- JUnit (or NUnit): Although there is more overhead in setting this up, you can get a lot of testing done with these frameworks. It's more low level than SoapUI (unless you use the SoapUI Groovy/Javascript engine), but with the level of control, you can accomplish more. However, this will require a full time developer to continue building/maintaining the tests.